# Sum function and copying that result to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that is to calculate the sum between two cells and then copy this result to another sheet, I would like the result to stay in f70 and then copy from there . But below code isnt work its put at 0 on input_6

```
wbMe.Sheets("blank3").Range("F70") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F68:G68"))
wbMe.Sheets("blank3").Range("F70").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("input_6").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is not a working . put 0 but i have on range some value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use copy/paste in this case.

Also, make sure to [qualify ALL of your references](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references) - in particular, the `Range("F68:G68")` refers to the currently active sheet, which may not be the one you want.

This code example hopefully shows you how to get what you want:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim wbMe As Workbook
    Dim b3 As Worksheet
    Dim in6 As Worksheet
    Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook
    Set b3 = wbMe.Sheets("blank3")
    Set in6 = wbMe.Sheets("input_6")
    
    b3.Range("F70").Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("F68:G68"))
    
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = in6.Cells(3, in6.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    in6.Cells(3, lastCol).Value = b3.Range("F70").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I got error "Application-definied or object - definied error" here in6.Cells(3, lastCol).Value = b3.Range("F70").Value . Is there a chance of the Sum's result directly copied from Range which is counted? not

Comment: Your error is likely because the `lastCol` is calculated as zero. Whatever is on row 3 of sheet `input_6` is not correctly giving you the last column number.

Comment: Ok i did now correctly sum function. But i have one more question. What would this function look like if, for example, with b3 I needed to paste another value under the 3rd line, e.g. range (f72) to sheet in 6 on the 4th Row and so on

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but you could create a loop to copy the same value to cells on multiple rows. Something like `Dim i As Long; For i = 3 to <lastRowToPaste>; in6.Cells(i, lastCol).Value = b3.Range("F70").Value; Next i`

Comment: I mean go example B68> T2
F70> T3
B70> T4.. Value frome b68 to rows 2 value from f70 to 3 and so on